# Is there any way to see how many unique views a page I linked to has got?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Is there a way to see how many unique views a linked question has got.

i.e. if I click link and then tweet the url e.g. [Can I set "Treat all wireless networks as public" before i even connect to one](https://superuser.com/q/342529/27789) then when people look at that link it should start incrementing the count on the way to the announcer / booster / publicist badge. Is there any way to see how many unique views that link has got?

Comment: @Sathya - Cheers for that, the title makes sense now.

Comment: You're welcome! Also, similar thing has been requested earlier on Meta.SO ref: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67240/133693), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3230/133693)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest supporting (upvoting) the primary feature request on meta that Sathya pointed out:

[View progress towards Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67240/view-progress-towards-announcer-badge)

Not a bad idea, and I can't see a lot of harm in it.